# Disabling MacOS X auto-focus when moving mouse over to the top of fullscreen app

Tags: macos, macos-highsierra, usability

I have very recently started using a MacBook Pro, with Mac OS X High Sierra for work purposes. I have two external monitors, on each of which a fullscreen application is displayed. Whenever I move my mouse pointer from one fullscreen app to the top of the other fullscreen app, it switches focus to that app. The problem is, this usually happens only on accident, as I have no purpose of using such a feature intentionally. So anytime I think I'm about to enter a some text in one app, after moving my mouse physically out of the way, it moves the mouse cursor to the top of a different fullscreen app, thus switching focus to that app, and me entering input in the the wrong app.

Can this be disabled in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't disable this (well... you might be able to by editing plist files, but that's clunky and requires work. There's no checkbox in your system preferences to disable it.)

Try this instead:

Instead of using Apple's default full-screen mode, use the old (better) OS-X full screen mode:

```
Hold shift + option while clicking the green "full-screen" button.
```

Comment: Thanks. I prefer the convenience of the default full-screen mode, but this is a decent workaround.